# How do I run a single function over a loop parallely? Python 2.7.12

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I'm trying to parallelize a program which uses a single function in a for loop which updates a global list/variable parallely. How do I go about this and how can I pass values to the function?

The sample code looks like this,

```
#python 2.7.12
import random
sum=0

#sample function to take a random integer between 0 to i and add it to global variable sum
def hello(i):
    print "Thread Id :",i   #instead of i it should be the threadID
    sum=sum+random.randrange(0,i)

#main function  
i=1
for i in range(10): 
    hello(i)        #how to parallelize this function over a loop?
```

Edit 1 :
Tried using the Process from multiprocessing but don't know how to pass values to the functions and how to run it parallely over a loop.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
sum=0 

def Hello(): 
   print 'hello: starting' 
   sum=sum+i    #Don't know how to pass values here 
   print 'hello: finishing' 

if name == 'main': 
   p1 = Process(target=func1) 
   p1.start() 
   p1.join()
   print sum
```

Comment: Globals and threads don't mix very well.  It would be a much better design to have `hello()` return just the random part, and have the results summed up in the master loop.

Comment: @JohnGordon except these are processes, not threads. OP: can you post the `multiprocessing` code you tried?

Comment: @roganjosh This is the code I tried ,

from multiprocessing import Process

sum=0

def func1():
  print 'func1: starting'
  sum=sum+i      #Don't know how to pass values here
  print 'func1: finishing'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = Process(target=func1)
  p1.start()
  p1.join()

Comment: @ShoebAhmed Please edit the question to include the code that you tried, properly formatted. It's illegible as a comment.

Comment: @roganjosh New to stackoverflow, please do forgive my naiveness. I'll add the code to the question also.

Comment: @ShoebAhmed you have accepted an answer, so the question is effectively closed :)

Comment: Yeah, @pscuderi 's code works flawlessly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiprocessing.dummy.Pool, which takes the function followed by your parameters (see below).

You'll also need to worry about synchronization on your global variable (see below for an example of how to use Lock).

Also, unless you use "global sum" the sum inside your function is referring to a local sum variable (see below for global sum example).

threading.current_thread() gives you the thread id.

```
#python 2.7.12
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import threading
import random

lock = threading.Lock()

sum = 0

#sample function to take a random integer between 0 to i and add it to global variable sum
def hello(i):
    if (i == 0):
        return
    global sum
    print threading.current_thread()   #instead of i it should be the threadID
    r = random.randrange(0,i)
    lock.acquire()
    try:
        sum = sum + r
    finally:
        lock.release()

ThreadPool().map(hello, list(range(1, 11)))

print sum
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @pscuderi. I had a few questions regarding the code,

Comment: 1. In function hello(i), why did you return  if i == 0?
2. Could you explain where exactly is the function hello() running 10 times?

Comment: randrange was throwing an exception when i == 0, and I presumed r could only be 0 in that case so why bother adding it to the sum.

Comment: ThreadPool().map(hello, list(range(10))) calls hello 10 times, once for each value in the list returned by list(range(10)).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameters as a tuple to the args kwarg of the Process function: Here is the example from the docs:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Also what John Gordon said in his comment is true too. You will need to have the master process (which will be running the loop) handle the summing. What you are basically trying to do is a simple map/reduce job.

The map part is your hello function and the reduce is the sum. There are lots of examples of doing map/reduce jobs in python.

Look at using a Pipe or Shared Memory for handling the sum, both are detailed in the multiprocessing docs mentioned above.

Comment: This launches a single Process. The docs use something like this (for some unknown reason) but it doesn't leverage additional power from multi-core CPU

Comment: I was assuming you would put the new Process inside the loop which would create a new process for each iteration of the loop and put the join outside the loop. A more elegant solution would be to use a pool as suggested by pscuderi

Comment: You can launch multiple processes in much the same manner as you have done, and chunk the data to be processed first (in a list comprehension fed with individual chunks or a `for` loop). Pass each process it's own unique chunk. Your approach does mirror the docs, but I've never understood how it addresses the GIL. I've not seen `multiprocessing.dummy` before so I need to look into that the understand the answer by pscuderi.